# Error while import resource file Business Data Connectivity

Tags: powershell, bcs

I am trying to use powershell for importing a resource file in Business Data Catalog but I keep getting the following error

```
Import-SPBusinessDataCatalogModel : The root element of a valid
Metadata package must be 'Model' in namespace
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2007/BusinessDataCatalog'. The root in the given package is 'Model' in namespace'http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2007/BusinessDataCatalog/Resources'.

Error was encountered at or just before Line: '2' and Position: '2'. At M:\PowerShell\ImportModel.ps1:13 char:35
+  Import-SPBusinessDataCatalogModel <<<<  -Path $file.FullName -Identity $bdc -force -ModelsIncluded -PropertiesIncluded -Verbose
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...alogModelCmdlet:SPImportSPBusinessDataCatalogModelCmdlet)
[Impo     rt-SPBusinessDataCatalogModel], PackageFormatException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.SharedService.SPImportSPBusinessDataCatalogModelCmdlet
```

When I manualy import the resource file everything is ok.

This is the resource file i Use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?>
<Model xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2007/BusinessDataCatalog/Resources" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="CZ.Sharepoint.BCS.Correspondentie.Zorg">
  <LobSystems>
    <LobSystem Name="Correspondentie">
      <Properties>
        <Property Name="WildcardCharacter" Type="System.String">%</Property>
      </Properties>
      <LobSystemInstances>
        <LobSystemInstance Name="Correspondentie">
          <Properties>
            <Property Name="AuthenticationMode" Type="System.String">PassThrough</Property>
            <Property Name="DatabaseAccessProvider" Type="System.String">SqlServer</Property>
            <Property Name="RdbConnection Data Source" Type="System.String">TSTSQL10</Property>
            <Property Name="RdbConnection Initial Catalog" Type="System.String">PRD_Correspondentie</Property>
            <Property Name="RdbConnection Integrated Security" Type="System.String">SSPI</Property>
            <Property Name="RdbConnection Pooling" Type="System.String">True</Property>
            <Property Name="ShowInSearchUI" Type="System.String"></Property>
          </Properties>
        </LobSystemInstance>
      </LobSystemInstances>
    </LobSystem>
  </LobSystems>
</Model>
```

And the powershell script

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$serviceContext = "http://localhost/"

$bdc = Get-SPBusinessDataCatalogMetadataObject -BdcObjectType Catalog -ServiceContext $serviceContext
$pathtobdcmfiles = Get-Location
$importFiles = Get-Childitem -path $pathtobdcmfiles | Where {$_.extension -eq ".bdcr" -and $_.basename -ne "catalog"}

foreach ($file in $importFiles) {
 Import-SPBusinessDataCatalogModel -Path $file.FullName -Identity $bdc -force -ModelsIncluded -PropertiesIncluded -Verbose
 write-host $file.fullname
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following script worked for me.  Im just importing properties but you could modify it to account for any other content contained in the resource file.

```
#imports the BCS resource file 
function ConfigureBCSModel([string]$path)
{
    $results = $null;

    # open the settings file
    $data = Get-Content $path

    # link to the central admin web context
    $centralAdmin = (Get-spwebapplication -includecentraladministration | where {$_.IsAdministrationWebApplication} | select Url -First 1).Url

    #connect to the bdc service
    $bdc = Get-SPBusinessDataCatalogMetadataObject -BdcObjectType Catalog -ServiceContext $centralAdmin

    #import the package
    $bdc.ImportPackage($data, [ref]$results, [Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.Parser.PackageContents]::Properties)

    # write out the import setting values
    foreach($result in $results)
    {
        Write-Host "Setting Import message: " $result;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to have the answer.  Have you tried changing your xmlns?

xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2007/BusinessDataCatalog/Resources"

to

xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2007/BusinessDataCatalog"

Comment: If i change that line i get the following error: Missing LobSystem (External System) Type information during Model import. Does the XML tha
t you are importing conform to the Resource schema instead of the Model schema?

Answer (score 0):

MLF Answer is correct. (Can't use comments yet.)
You get the next error because you haven't specified the Type attribute in your LobSystem element.

Here is an example
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817559.aspx